# Add new rows to related model on creation of parent model in Admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have models for adding products. The name of the products are in several languages, so I made a on-to-many raltion with a 'Name'-model.

This is my models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField()

class ProductName(models.Model):
    productName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    language = models.ForeignKey('Language', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.productName

class Language(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    languageAbbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.language
```

Now in the admin page of mysite, I want to add product names on creation of a product.
I tried some misarable attempt with some thing I found about 'admin.TabularInline'. But I think that is wrong because nothing is working with that.

Any suggestion about how to solve this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A model admin like this:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class ProductNameInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = ProductNameInline
        fields = ['productName', 'language']

    model = Product
    inlines = [ProductNameInline]
```

should provide you with a page that allows you set the name(s) of a product. 
Make sure all the necessary static files for the javascript are available.